# grab specific data from program output resutl in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using xubuntu in my laptop. When I want to type or code, the touchpad  relocate the curser. I want to disable thouchpad. The command "xinput list" shows the touchpad id so I can disable it with: xinput set-prop {touchpad id} "Device Enabled" 0
I want to use luncher for ease but when I restart laptop the touchpad id may change.
how can I grab touchpad id form xinput list command output and use it in xinput set-prop command?

Comment: `man synclient` (assuming it's installed on your laptop) might give you a reasonable alternative...

Answer (score 0):

you can create a small shell script that is run on start-up:

```
#!/bin/bash
TPAD_ID=$(xinput list | grep -i touchpad | sed 's/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/i')
xinput set-prop $TPAD_ID "Device Enabled" 0
```

The TouchPad ID is extracted from the output of `xinput list` and then fed to the command that you mentioned.